# Runtime exception from AsynchTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a Popup system that displays Popup alerts with a Textview. The Popup class (shown below) is called through an Intent from another class. The code for the Popup class works when the Popup is displayed on the onCreate method (the code that makes it is done is shown in block comments in the oncreate class). However, my function is to create the popups so that it does not stop/pause the background applications. Pretty much get the functionality of a Toast. Display the Popup without interrupting the background apps. So I have decided to implement this using AsynchTask but I keep getting a the run time exception. Could someone guide me in the right path? I believe I must implement a onPostExecute but not sure how I should go about this.

```
public class Popups extends Activity {
 private Dialog mDialog;
//static final String ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.popups);

    //IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ACTION);
    //this.registerReceiver(mReceivedSMSReceiver, filter);
    /*
    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");

    TextView messageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    messageView.setText(message);

    Handler handler = new Handler();
    long delay = 5000;

    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Popups.this.finish();
        }
    }, delay);
    */
    PopupAsynch myPopup = new PopupAsynch();
    myPopup.execute(1);
}
private class PopupAsynch extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Integer>
{
    TextView messageView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.message);
    String message = getIntent().getStringExtra("message");
    @Override
    protected Integer doInBackground(Integer... params) {


        Handler handler = new Handler();
        long delay = 5000;

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Popups.this.finish();
            }
        }, delay);

        messageView.setText(message);   

        return 1;

    }

}


}
```

Comment: i don't quite get what your asynctask does (It doesn't look right) but most important you shouldn't touch the UI (setText) from a background thread.

Comment: `messageView.setText(message);`   put it onPostexecute method.

Comment: and asynctask won't help you with your goal keeping other apps/activities, they will still all get onPaused when this Activity gets called.

Comment: @Su-AuHwang would u elaborate more on that? I was believed Asynch would work for me

Comment: @geet I tried that earlier. It has no effect

Comment: when you start an Activity (Popup) that has a view, it (at least) partially covers your calling activity, thus onPause definitely gets called. Asynctask won't help you, since you still have to start your popup activity, and while it's active (event waiting) all other activities are getting onPaused or even stopped. You should reconsider your approach and try a custom Toast.

Answer (score 0):

First this Implementation of showing Popup is Incorrect.

Second Handler which you have created is not attached with your UI thread, you need to call Looper on this Handler to attach it with UI thread.

Instead of this AsyncTask if you use your commented code that would be better.

Comment: I am using a textview as popup
What did you mean by the Looper? I can use my commented code and it works fine but the problem is, when a popup is showed everything is paused then after the popup disappears, it resume. I just want it not interrupt anything

Answer (score 0):

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

This is using AsyncTask thread looper. And any attempt to change UI from it will result in an error.

AsyncTask in your code seems useless. Why not post delayed to main handler from Activity code only ?

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean by "post delayed to main handler from Activity code" You want me to keep the delay in the Actiivity and move the settext etc to the Asynch?

Comment: he means, just using this in onCreate():
    Handler handler = new Handler();
  handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
   
   @Override
   public void run() {
    Popup.this.finish();
   }
  }, 5000);

Comment: and remove your asynctask completely will have the same effect as your current code, but it still won't solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Use timer to implement this properly**

```
private Timer timer;

timer = new Timer();
                    timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    Popups.this.finish();
                                    messageView.setText(message); 
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }, 0, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks I think the timer is more efficient. Should I include in this all in the doInBackground method? or should I put the messageView.setText() in onPostExecute?